# Including files with names in array

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to include pile of files to my page, using array for the file names.

```
$arr=array(01,02,03,04); 
foreach ($arr as $filename) { 
  $filename="pars/".$filename.".inc"; 
  include $filename; 
}
```

I also tried this code:

```
$arr=array(01,02,03,04);
foreach ("pars/".$arr.".inc" as $filename) { include $filename; }
```

Now I use simplier combination to include all files in directory:

```
foreach (glob("pars/*.inc") as $filename) { include $filename; }
```

But I need to make including optional. Where is my fault? Or is there simplier way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array must be string:

```
$arr=array('01','02','03','04');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to take a different approach at this.

PHP does provide autoloading classes.

Take a look at these 2 links: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: This is great idea for classes, but my inc files contains table rows <tr> with information. So, when I include all files, page generates <table>. Inc files appears and dissapears dynamically, so, people are monitoring information IRL. Now I need to give different rows to different people. Of course I can make many files with custom includes, but I try to find easier solution to maintain.